# warning C4114: same type qualifier used more than once

Tags: c++, visual-c++, constants

On migrating a VC++ 6.0 developed code to Visual studio 2008, I got this warning in the line below in my code.

```
const int const CImportContext::PACKETSIZE = 4096;
```

I know how to fix for pointer

```
static const int const * PACKETSIZE;   // C4114
static const int * const PACKETSIZE;   // Correct
```

But my question is how to fix this warning, if its like the one below(without pointer),

```
static const int const PACKETSIZE;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pointers have two different kinds of `const` qualifiers makes sense, one is for the pointer itself, the other for what the pointer points.

But it doesn't make sense for `int` type to have two different kinds of `const` qualifiers. Just use one:

```
const int CImportContext::PACKETSIZE = 4096;
```

or

```
int const CImportContext::PACKETSIZE = 4096;
```

Answer (score 0):

the "const" qualifier is left-associative, it always applies to it's left side data type except for cases where there is no left side data type so only in that case it will go for it's right side data type. the data types in your examples are "int" and "*" - applying "const" to either or both of them can make sense. applying it twice to a single data type is not useful but hints for an issue - that is the reason for the warning.
("static" is a qualifier for storage. "PACKETSIZE" is the variable object name.)